# Perplexing Windows Calculator behaviour

Tags: windows-7, windows, calculator

On Windows 7, launching Calculator and typing `9/8[Enter]7[Enter]6[Enter]`, and other similar sequences of keypresses, results in an apparently odd behaviour.

For instance `9/8[Enter]7[Enter]` outputs `0.875`, and `9/8[Enter]7[Enter]6[Enter]` outputs `0.75`.

A friend of mine noticed that `p/q[Enter]r` seems to give `((p/q) - floor(p/q))*r`.

What's going on?

Comment: Click view, then history, what does that tell you?

Comment: Ha! That explains it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [Tog](https://superuser.com/users/51300/tog), viewing the Calculator History (`Ctrl-H`) illuminates what's going on here.

[image: Windows Calculator, with the History pane showing: 9/8 [Newline] 7/8 [Newline] 6/8.]

Entering `9/8` sets "divide by 8" as the operation enacted on all subsequent inputted numbers. Calculator works the same way with other binary operations as well.